# Microservices - compensate service failure with queue

Tags: microservices, message-queue

We are using some sort of microservices approach in our app (although it is not really consequently adhered to).

When a service is down or throwing an exception, the approach is to put it into a queue (ActiveMQ), and retry when the service is up again.

Is this a "standard" solution? Or should it be avoided for some reason?

Or is there a better, or alternative solution to this problem?

Comment: What's the problem with the current solution? The best/better solution is the one that totally fit your requirements. Do so the current one?

Comment: @Laiv: There is no problem per se, but as I am not that experienced with that architecture, I was just asking, if there are any potential problems or limitations of this approach which should be considered.

Comment: What happens if the queue is down?

Comment: @JonRaynor: give up and return an error, as it would probably be overkill to implement a second fallback mechanism...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you can make your calls asynchronous (you do not need to get a response from the service in order to proceed), doing so is often a good idea.

It allows the calling service to continue working without the delay (or outright error) caused by calling the other service. It allows you to have more complex retry logic and to spread out the load more evenly over time.

For many cases, you can get even more out of it by giving up on the ordering guarantees provided by queues and switch to [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/) or another asynchronous message broker. [Hermes](https://github.com/allegro/hermes) provides a more convenient REST API on top of Kafka.

Comment: I upvote this answer assuming the context is that we are talking about the client.  This isn't really a micro-services question.  It's a client design decision.  If the service is either synchronous or not and it's either up or it's not.  It's not clearly spelled out in the question but it really only makes sense if we are talking about a client.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad approach in my view. you should either

- Always communicate view a queue : Your application should not expect an immediate response and hence the worker process does not have to be 100% available
- Always use RPC style comms. Load balance requests across multiple service instances : If a service is faulty another will answer the request, so you have 100% uptime

Having the flow, call service, get error, place in queue, remember to check queue for replies to some of my messages for but not all of them. is over complicated.

edit : over complicated in that you have to program both the sync and async style of communication rather than just one or the other.

Comment: I kind of agree with this. It is *more* complicated. Whether it's *too* complicated is hard to evaluate without understanding the larger architecture. The issue with going 100% queue-based is that it adds new single-point of failure and creates some other challenges. For example if your process is getting overwhelmed with tasks, writing to the queue is generally really fast so there's no apparent problem on the input side until **boom** the queue fills up. If the source of the requests can't be throttled, you have can have a big problem. Not insurmountable but it adds it's own complexity.

Comment: If I may, I would suggest rewording the last sentence.  'Remembering' isn't really a problem here, once the code is written to read from the queue, there's nothing to remember.  It's simply additional code to write and maintain but it shouldn't look much different from what you would have if you always read from the queue.

Comment: in the only errors goto queue senario AND you want replies you have to write both the queue check AND the immediate response handling. So you have to 'remember' those erred calls and not the immediate ones

Comment: @jimmy you get those problems with any solution. queue always, queue sometimes or all RPC.

Comment: You really don't have some of these problems when you producers are waiting for the consumers.  For example, if you a receiving a max of 1000 requests a second, and your processes internal capacity drops to 100 a second, your producers will be blocked in a straightforward approach.  They will be limited also.  If you simply insert a queue in the middle, the producers will generally be unaffected by the drop in capacity and continue at their max rate.  The queue will then fill up until you hit it's capacity limit and the writes start failing (at 1000 failures a second.)

Comment: either way, queue or rpc your system is throwing errors when it hits capacity. both approaches have ways of mitigating the problem

Comment: Not in the same way, no.  If you have producers waiting for responses, the volume they are pushing is limited by blocking.  There's an inherent feedback. This itself can be a problem but it's easy to understand.  When you insert a queue, you cut the coupling between the performance of the consumer and the producer.  That's one of the main benefits of queues.  Queues can be useful for certain types of problems but they create complexities that are not obvious until you've spent a lot of time debugging them.

Comment: the equivalent error would be a timeout. its only because people are used to timeouts rather than queues filling up that one seems obvious and the other difficult

Comment: To give a concrete example, we had system that was using a major vendor's queuing system: one that has been around for a really long time.  This queuing system has an unexpected 'feature' that as the queue depth grows, it takes longer to read a single message from the queue.  Things would work fine as long as the queues were cleared.  But if the reader stopped things would build up and if it hit a certain depth, it was impossible to catch up without stopping the writers completely and wait for hours.

Comment: It seems that way on the surface but it's not the case.  The mechanisms and symptoms of the failures are very different.  And this is just one of the challenges of queuing.  You also have to think about whether you need persistance and the IO overhead of that.  I've seen queues take down a SAN causing failures in unrelated systems. (it was a crappy one but devastating all the same).  Additionally if you force requests through a queuing system, if it's offline, you are offline.

Comment: it seems like you have many queuing war stories, but I could equally roll off a dozen about RPC style setups. At the end of the day all systems have limits. theres not an inherent flaw with the idea of queues/async operations

Comment: Queuing has its place and if when it comes to async processing, it can be a useful tool albeit a lot of the features are obsolete and/or oversold e.g. guaranteed messaging. What I strongly recommend against is inserting a queue into the middle of a synchronous process.  There are far better ways to scale.  As I said in my comment on the other answer, this kind of thing only makes sense in a client.  Even then, there are probably better ways to address the need to reprocess on errors.